# The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a communication problem between my ASP.NET website and WCF services, which are both on the same machine.

Error thrown by WCF service:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005) The client and
>   server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common
>   algorithm (NativeErrorCode: 80090331)

This is on the client side:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{ 

    bool isValid = false; 

    using (DynamicProxy<IExtranetMembershipService> client = new DynamicProxy<IExtranetMembershipService>(false)) 
    { 
        isValid = client.Impl.ValidateUser(applicationName, username, password); 
    } 
    return isValid; 
}
```

On server side it throws the upper message, that I've posted above.

Comment: How about you post some code so that we have some idea of what's going on?

Comment: Please post your trials and errors in a [MCVE]

Comment: This is on the client side: public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            using (DynamicProxy<IExtranetMembershipService> client = new DynamicProxy<IExtranetMembershipService>(false))
            {
                isValid = client.Impl.ValidateUser(applicationName, username, password);
            }
            return isValid;
        } On server side it throws the upper message, that I've posted in the question.

Comment: Please don't add useful information like that to a comment. Please add any attempts you have made to the question itself so it is not only clearer for those trying to answer, but also to those who come across this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. It turns out that the protocol TLS 1.2 should be disabled and I had to install the latest updates for .NET Framework 4.6.1.